# How do I quickly find if a big number $\bmod n$ is odd or even?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I quickly find if big number is even or odd?
For example I want to find if $17^{50}\mod 101$ even or odd ?

Comment: hint : even mod even is even , odd mod even = odd also type^something is type where type is either even or odd

Comment: @Agawa001 except the OP is not asking about whether $17^{50}$ is even or odd (it's odd) but if the reduce residue of $17^{5)} \mod 101$ and odd mod odd is not consistent.

Comment: Interestingly a^50 = +/- 1 modulo 101 for 1 ≤ a ≤ 100. Which doesn't help one bit with the question :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general numbers, you just divide by $2$. For the question you've asked, I'm assuming you're asking the the least positive residue of $17^{50} \bmod 101$ is odd or even. Since exponentiation is so fast in modular arithmetic, I would recommend simply computing $17^{50} \bmod 101$ through repeated squaring.

In this particular case, you can be a bit more clever if you know some elementary number theory. By Fermat's little Theorem, we know that $17^{100} \equiv 1 \pmod{101}$. As $101$ is prime, the only square roots of $1$ are $\pm 1$. So we have $17^{50} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{101}$. Which one depends on whether or not $17$ is a quadratic residue mod $101$.

Using Legendre symbols, you can perform the sequence of operations
$$\newcommand{kron}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right)}
\kron{17}{101} = \kron{101}{17} = \kron{16}{17} = 1.$$
So $17$ is a square mod $101$ (so $17$ is not a primitive root), which means that $17^{50} \equiv 1 \pmod {101}$. So it's odd.

Answer (score 2):

Convert $50$ to binary and read out its bits: $50 = 32+16+2$.

Compute successive squares of $17$ and keep a running product of those powers corresponding to the list of bits:  \begin{align}
    17^2 &\cong 289 \cong 87 \pmod{101}  &  17^2 &\cong 87 \pmod{101}  \\
    17^4 &\cong 87^2 \cong 95 \cong -6 \pmod{101}  \\
    17^8 &\cong (-6)^2 \cong 36 \pmod{101}  \\
    17^{16} &\cong 36^2 \cong 84 \pmod{101}  &  17^{16+2} &\cong 87 \cdot 84 \cong 36 \pmod{101}  \\
    17^{32} &\cong 84^2 \cong 87 \pmod{101}  &  17^{32+16+2} &\cong 36 \cdot 87 \cong 1 \pmod{101}  \text{,}
\end{align} and $1$ is odd.

The are *other* shortcuts, unfortunately, for odd modulus, they're not useful.  For instance, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), we know, since $101$ is prime, $17^{100} \cong 1 \pmod{101}$, so $17^{50} \cong \pm 1 \pmod{101}$, but $1$ is odd and $-1 \cong 100$ is even, so this doesn't help much.

Comment: $17^{32}\equiv 87$ should bring you up short, since then $17^{32} \equiv 17^2$ which gives you $\text{ord}_{101}(17) \mid 30 \implies \text{ord}_{101}(17) \mid 10 \implies 17^{50}\equiv 1$.

Comment: @Joffan : I suppose.  But by then it's too late.  You already have all the powers of $17$ you're ever going to need, do the one multiplication, and the one reduction and be done.

Comment: To be honest I noticed at $17^{16} \equiv -17 \implies 17^{15}\equiv -1$. So maybe I should've said that :-)